# NVD3 and D3 : What caused my data to be unbound from tooltip?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have a situation where I have found the solution but I would like to understand why my solution is working.
I am working with a NVD3 multiBarChart and implementing a discrete bar chart look when the user is only showing data across 1 dimension.

In the process, this block of code was what I used to target an SVG rectangle and change its color:

```
d3.select("svg .nv-series-0").select("rect:nth-child(2)").attr("style","fill: #d34356; stroke: #d34356;");
```

The code above correctly changed the color but removed (or corrupted) the data bound to the rect and mouseover events for this rect no longer worked. Without this adjustment the mousover event fired correctly showing the data for the rect.

I modified the d3 selection in the code to:

```
d3.select("svg .nv-series-0 rect:nth-child(2)").attr("style","fill: #d34356; stroke: #d34356;");
```

And this works, the data for the mouseover events is still there for the rectangle.

Can anyone explain how and why the original d3.select followed by another .select affected the data that was passed for the mouseover event?